# No matching function for call to 'CFastLED::addLeds(CRGB [6], int)

Tags: c++, arduino, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to execute this ino code on Arduino Nano w/ATmega328 board (LED lights) but I am getting "**no matching function for call to 'CFastLED::addLeds(CRGB [6], int)**" error.

Any idea what could be the cause? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
#include "FastLED.h"
#define NUM_LEDS 6
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {
  LEDS.addLeds<TM1803>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}
```

Comment: Not `FastLED.addLeds<>()`?

Comment: I've added "FastLED. addLeds<>()" instead of "LEDS.addLeds<TM1803>" still same error.

Comment: I dunno anything about this library, but the doc examples take two template arguments, e.g. `FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, 4>(leds, NUM_LEDS_PER_STRIP);`

Comment: I Have tried that too. but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience in Arduino, but here is what I've unerstood after reading [FastLED.h](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/master/FastLED.h).

`TM1803` is [declared as](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/master/FastLED.h#L58):

```
template<uint8_t DATA_PIN, EOrder RGB_ORDER>
class TM1803 : public TM1803Controller400Khz<DATA_PIN, RGB_ORDER> {};
```

So `LEDS.addLeds()` should somehow invoke one of [these two overloads](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/master/FastLED.h#L154):

```
template<template<uint8_t DATA_PIN, EOrder RGB_ORDER> class CHIPSET, uint8_t DATA_PIN, EOrder RGB_ORDER>
static CLEDController &addLeds(struct CRGB *data, int nLedsOrOffset, int nLedsIfOffset = 0) {
    static CHIPSET<DATA_PIN, RGB_ORDER> c;
    return addLeds(&c, data, nLedsOrOffset, nLedsIfOffset);
}

template<template<uint8_t DATA_PIN, EOrder RGB_ORDER> class CHIPSET, uint8_t DATA_PIN>
static CLEDController &addLeds(struct CRGB *data, int nLedsOrOffset, int nLedsIfOffset = 0) {
    static CHIPSET<DATA_PIN, RGB> c;
    return addLeds(&c, data, nLedsOrOffset, nLedsIfOffset);
}
```

So you have to specify either `DATA_PIN` or both `DATA_PIN` and `RGB_ORDER` in template paramenters, whatever they mean:

```
LEDS.addLeds<TM1803, SOME_DATA_PIN, SOME_RGB_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS); 
LEDS.addLeds<TM1803, SOME_DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and error.  The above helped me edit my code so that it worked.  I had to add template parameters (had never heard of those before) for LED type and Data pin.  Here's my definitions and code:

```
#include <FastLED.h>  
//#define DEBUG 1
#define LED_TYPE WS2812
#define NUM_LEDS 64
#define DATA_PIN A14 
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup()
{ 
FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}
```

I used WS2812 as a guess because my matrix LEDs were WS2812B-64.  Apparently the first part was sufficient.